# Working with a list of dictionaries in ansible

Tags: ansible

i'm working on an ansible-based post-deployment check. to perform the check, i need to combine some static information that i can hardcode into playbook, with some dynamic information that is only available at run-time. i can't seem to find the right ansible syntax to express this.
here's python-based description of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
# dummy definitions, just so the code is runable

def run_shell(cmd):
  print('run:', cmd)
  return { "stdout": cmd }

def uri(obj):
  print(obj, "success" if obj["port"] % 2 == 0 else "failure" )
# end dummy definitions

# this is what i would like to have implemented in Ansible
ports = [
  { "name": "app 1", "port": 1111},
  { "name": "app 2", "port": 2222},
  { "name": "app 3", "port": 3333},
]

for app in ports:
  result = run_shell(f'./get_metadata {app["name"]}')
  app["metadata"] = result["stdout"]                   # <-- this is what i'm having trouble with

for app in ports:
  uri(app)                                             # <-- this is what i want to run,
                                                       # that needs static data hardcoded above
                                                       # but also dynamic data obtained from shell
```

is this even possible with ansible?

Comment: What structure of *app* do you expect? [edit] the question and provide an example of *app*.

Comment: No dynamic data are used in *def uri(obj)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [ansible loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

---

You can register the result of a `command`/`shell` task as with any other task. If you register with a loop (see above reference) the `results` key will contain a list of all results from each iteration.

The object in the list contains all attributes returned by the tasks (so we will have `stdout` and `stdout_lines` in our case) as well as an `item` key containing the original item the task was played against.

The following dummy example should give you the idea. The `test.yml` dummy playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    hostsports:
      - name: app 1
        port: 1111
      - name: app 2
        port: 2222
      - name: app 3
        port: 3333

  tasks:
    - name: Run (a dummy example) command for all elements in list
      ansible.builtin.command: "echo '{{ item.name }}:{{ item.port }}'"
      register: app_check
      loop: "{{ hostsports }}"

    - name: Loop over results and display something
      vars:
        some_dummy_flag: "{{ item.stdout is search('2222') }}"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - "Original name is: {{ item.item.name }}"
          - "Original port is: {{ item.item.port }}"
          - "Command result for item is: {{ item.stdout }}"
          - "Command result is considered: {{ 'success' if some_dummy_flag else 'failure' }}"
      loop: "{{ app_check.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

results in:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Run (a dummy example) command for all elements in list] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'app 1', 'port': 1111})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'app 2', 'port': 2222})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'app 3', 'port': 3333})

TASK [Loop over results and display something] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'app 1', 'port': 1111}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Original name is: app 1",
        "Original port is: 1111",
        "Command result for item is: app 1:1111",
        "Command result is considered: failure"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'app 2', 'port': 2222}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Original name is: app 2",
        "Original port is: 2222",
        "Command result for item is: app 2:2222",
        "Command result is considered: success"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'app 3', 'port': 3333}) => {
    "msg": [
        "Original name is: app 3",
        "Original port is: 3333",
        "Command result for item is: app 3:3333",
        "Command result is considered: failure"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the list

```yaml
  ports:
    - {name: app 1, port: 1111}
    - {name: app 2, port: 2222}
    - {name: app 3, port: 3333}
```

Create a script for testing

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/get_metadata 
echo metadata of $1
```

Iterate the command and register the result

```yaml
    - command:
        cmd: sh -c "./get_metadata '{{ item.name }}'"
        chdir: /tmp/test
      loop: "{{ ports }}"
      register: result
```

Create a list of the *stdout* in the results

```yaml
 metadata: "{{ result.results|json_query('[].{metadata: stdout}') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  metadata:
  - metadata: metadata of app 1
  - metadata: metadata of app 2
  - metadata: metadata of app 3
```

Combine the items on the lists

```yaml
  app: "{{ ports|zip(metadata)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  app:
  - metadata: metadata of app 1
    name: app 1
    port: 1111
  - metadata: metadata of app 2
    name: app 2
    port: 2222
  - metadata: metadata of app 3
    name: app 3
    port: 3333
```

Comment: while your approach maintains the structure, i would prefer to limit the use of filtering expressions, because they are harder to read.